# using the same string interpolation inside the method as on its define_method line

Tags: ruby

bonus problem in Ruby Monk

> Create a class Monk which can meditate on life, the universe or
>   everything. It should have three methods meditate_on_life,
>   meditate_on_the_universe & meditate_on_everything and returns strings
>   of "I know the meaning of life", "I know the meaning of the universe",
>   and "I know the meaning of everything", respectively.

building on the previous problems in this chapter, it should look something like this

```
class Monk
  ["life", "the_universe", "everything"].each do |element|
    define_method("meditate_on_#{element}").each do |argument|
      "I know the meaning of #{element.gsub('meditate_on_', '').gsub('_', ' ')}"
    end
  end
end
```

what's the right way to make that string inside the defined method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. `define_method(....).each` does not make sense. And the methods do not seem to need any arguments. Also, `element` does not include `meditate_on_`, so there is no need to remove it.

```
class Monk
  ["life", "the_universe", "everything"].each do |element|
    define_method("meditate_on_#{element}") do
      "I know the meaning of #{element.gsub('_', ' ')}"
    end
  end
end
Monk.new.meditate_on_life
# => "I know the meaning of life"
```

Comment: oops, my mistake on the second `each do` and the `element.gsub`, just some nonsense I forgot to correct from earlier draft